# Module development workflow with GIT and modman

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, best-practice, git, modman

This question is a follow up of this one: [Magento 1: improving my module development workflow (Modman, composer, git)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/159544/2380)

Reminder:

> I am using a bunch of extensions that me and the team I'm working with
>   have developped (here we're talking 50+ extensions) and the code for
>   those extensions is stored on Bitbucket

I've changed my development workflow to the following:

At the moment, when I want to add a feature/fix a bug for one of those extensions, here's my workflow:

- Install the last version of the extension on one of the website via Modman with symlinks
- Fix the bug/add a feature/test by modifying the files in `.modman` module folder
- Go the `.modman` module folder and commit/push my module changes (thus the bitbucket repo for this extension will be updated)
- Go back to my root folder and commit and push via GIT to the website repo

My problem now is that **Assembla does not seem to recognize the symlinks from that last commit/push step**.

It gives me a weird icon (like it doesn't know if it's a file or a folder):

[image]

If I check the commit here's what I see:

[image]

I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing here but **when my team mates pull the repo on their side, their `.modman` folder ends up being empty.**

NB: something I noticed when I pushed my changes to the website repo is that **I tend to get a GIT error: "fatal: git cat-file: couldn not get object info" but the commit is still pushed.** I'm not sure if it's related though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It gives me a weird icon (like it doesn't know if it's a file or a folder):

It's a broken git submodule. This happens if you accidently commit a directory that contains a `.git` directory.

To prevent that, use the following in your last step

```
git add .modman/Vendor_Module/*
```

The `/*` adds all files in the directory, **excluding those starting with a dot**

Note that if you have files starting with a dot in the module's root directory (like `.gitignore`) you will have to add them manually.

#### How to fix the broken submodules

First remove the submodule from the repository (`--cached` makes sure to not change your workspace)

```
git rm --cached .modman/Vendor_Module
```

Then re-add the files as described above.

Comment: When I do that I get `fatal: Path '.modman/Vendor_Module/app' is in submodule '.modman/Vendor_Module'`